# How is the desired output of a neural network represented so as to be compared with the actual output?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

A neural network learns to approximate the desired output and hence one can use unknown testing sets and classify each testing example according to its respective class. For example a neural network can learn to classify handwritten digits and recognise a handwritten '9' to be the value 9.

How does the neural network compare the output of the training sample with the desired output? What encoding does the desired output take in the structure of the neural network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea is that you don't create one single output for everything and ask it "what digit is this??". You create one output for each digit, and you ask each one "is this digit x??".

So, the desired output must be encoded with a 1Xn vector, where n is the number of classes. All values will be 0, and the value corresponding to the desired class will be 1. In your case for example, create a 1X10 vector, and encode zero as

```
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

one as

```
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

and nine as

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
```

For the actual output, create a perceptron with 10 outputs. Each output will give a value in [0,1]. The output with the max value wins, and is regarded as 1, while all the others are regarded as 0. So, if the output of your network is

```
[0.1 0.05 0.02 0.92 0.4 ....]
```

these correspond to the votes for digits [0 1 2 3 4 ..], so the number suggested by the classifier is three